# call onQueryTextChange while pressing backspace (delete) key

Tags: android, searchview

in my search view , when i delete my query's text using my backspace (delete) key no results got returned please see the below images for better understanding

see here i search for `test1` which is an object in my adapter and am getting the result..

[image: image1]

okay here i queried one more time but i have none objects with this name so am not getting anything as result which is fine

[image]

now here i pressed backspace(delete key) and now my query text is `test` and i have a object with this name in my adapter but am not getting any thing in return 
[image]

my `onQueryTextChange` is being called when deleting the texts of query.    how can fix this ?? any clue ??

codes:

```
Search_View.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String Text) {

                return false;
            }
                @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (newText.length() == 0) {
                    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(), getData());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter);
                }
                if ( notesAdapter != null) {
                    notesAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

my notesAdapter's filtering portion:

```
private static class UserFilter extends Filter {

    private final NotesAdapter adapter;

    private final List<Information> originalList;

    private final List<Information> filteredList;

    private UserFilter(NotesAdapter adapter, List<Information> originalList) {
        super();
        this.adapter = adapter;
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(originalList);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        filteredList.clear();
        final FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(originalList);



        } else {
            final String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();


            for (final Information user : originalList) {




                    if ( (user.title != null && user.title.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) ||(user.address != null &&(user.address.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern))) ||
                            (user.postType != null && (user.postType.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) )|| (user.publisher != null&& (user.publisher.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)))
                            )

                    {
                        filteredList.add(user);

                    }

            }
        }
        results.values = filteredList;
        results.count = filteredList.size();
        return results;
    }


    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        adapter.filteredUserList.clear();
        if  ((ArrayList<Information>) results.values != null ) {

            adapter.filteredUserList.addAll((ArrayList<Information>) results.values);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    } }
```

Comment: `"seems like my onQueryTextChange is not being called..."` seems? didnt you check it?

Comment: @pskink yeah its being called , just confirmed it

Comment: put down your code also

Comment: please Check my updated question @Stallion

Comment: why are you calling `recyclerView.setAdapter(notesAdapter)` multiple times in `onQueryTextChange`? call it just once

Comment: for reseting the RecyclerView when the searchQuery gets empty ? isn't good ?

Comment: post your `NotesAdapter`, where are you getting the data from?

Comment: @pskink here you go

Comment: @remyboys found any solution?
M having Same Problem

Comment: @remyboys Can you post your `NoteAdapter`..

Answer (score 0):

I've Created one method inside my adapter to apply search function.

Here is what I've did..

**CustomAdaperte**

```
//Original list to be used for adapter
private List<CustomerPaid> customerList;
//Same list used for search
private List<CustomerPaid> tempCustomerListForSearch;

public CustomAdapter(List<CustomerPaid> customerList) {
        this.customerList = customerList;
        tempCustomerListForSearch = new ArrayList<>();
        tempCustomerListForSearch.addAll(customerList);
}

/**
 * Filters the data stored in list
 * @param textSearch
 */
public void filter(String textSearch){
    textSearch = textSearch.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());

    customerList.clear();

    if (textSearch.length() == 0) {

        customerList.addAll(tempCustomerListForSearch);
    } else {

        for (CustomerPaid customerPaid : tempCustomerListForSearch) {
            if (customerPaid.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(textSearch))
                customerList.add(customerPaid);
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return customerList.size();
}
```

Inside your activity:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                customAdapter.filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```